# In Perforce, how do I re-add a file that was deleted during a back-out?

Tags: perforce

Here's our situation:

- We copied the contents of stream A, which was change to our security infrastructure up into main.
- Then we merged the contents down into stream B.
- Then we made some other non-related changes in stream B.
- Then we realized the changes from stream A weren't working as well as we thought and we decided to back it out to be safe.
- We backed out the revision that included the updates from stream A.
- This had the effect of deleting some of the files and changing others.
- We tested without the stream A changes, and everything worked.
- Meanwhile, the developers made a couple of small changes in stream A and we are ready to merge stream A back into stream B.

The problem is, we can copy up to main, but we can't get those changes back down into stream B, as the "remove stream A" changes are newer.  We want all the changes we previously backed out *back in*, as well as the new changes.

Is there any way to do this without resorting to a tremendous manual effort to either manually copy or manually merge everything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start by running `p4 changes -i @n,n` where n is the changelist number of the merge from main to B that contained the A changes you backed out. That gives you a list of changes, the first of which is n itself, and the rest are the changes in main that you will need to re-merge to B. However, you can't use 'p4 merge' to re-merge, but instead will have to use 'p4 integ -f'.

For example, say n is 1000:

```
p4 changes -i @1000,1000
Change 1000 ...
Change 994  ...
Change 991  ...
Change 866  ...
```

This tells you that you have to re-merge 866, 991, and 994 from main to B. If you weren't cherrypicking, you can assume that these are contiguous changes in main and that you can use 866 thru 994 as a revision range:

```
p4 integ -f -r -S //stream/B @866,994
p4 resolve
p4 submit
```

(This integ command example assumes that //stream/main is the parent of //stream/B. And you have to be in a //stream/B workspace to do this, of course. And for best results, you probably want to make sure your workspace is completely synced and that you have no open files before running the integ.)

Comment: A is not the parent.  They are both spawned from the //stream/main, though at different times.  When //stream/B was created, //stream/A had been updated to main.  So... I guess then, I could use main & B and that would work...

Comment: I misunderstood your scenario (not that you were unclear; I just wasn't paying attention) and reworded my answer accordingly. The examples commands don't change, just the reference to 'main' as parent of B instead of A.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Perforce streams, but traditionally Perforce does not have any special notion of backouts.  Backing out a change simply creates an inverse changeset.

Therefore, to reapply a backed-out change, you should be able to just back out the backout.

Answer (score 1):

You can always backout your backed out changelist. This way you'll get to the point where the first changes were made.

Bear in mind that all files history is saved so all changes are supposed to be easily recovered in situations like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Your most recent change is the delete, so it wouldn't re-add the file as its already opened for delete. Run a p4 revert on that file, and then do a p4 add, it worked for me.